# throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, schema

I wrote the below schema. But while running it gives me an error -- throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}` is not ` + --- can someone help me why does this error comes?. Below shown is my schema, can someone figure out if my schema have some mistakes.

```
    $
jsonSchema: {
                bsonType: "object",
                properties: {

                    name: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        description: "must be a string"
                    },
                    teacherId: {
                        bsonType: "objectId",
                        description: "must be a Object ID"
                    }
                }    
            }
```

Comment: If you are using mongoose, you should use the mongoose syntax for [defining a schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). Currently you are using the native mongodb syntax

Comment: Could you please help me about to know what changes should I make for the above schema? @TheeSritabtim

Comment: how I am possible to make  acess the schema  from the controller

Comment: I have added the answer for defining schema. Accessing the schema from the controller is a separate question, please post a new question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the MongoDB native syntax to define your schema. If you are using mongoose, mongoose has its own syntax. Please refer to mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). For your schema it would be:

```
var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  teacherId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
})
```

Comment: I would like to follow the mongoDB native syntax and proceed

Comment: Keep in mind that the native approach to validation is a bit different in concept than mongoose's. More about it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/234871

Answer (score 0):

Mmm how I resolved this was to use the Types defined within the Schema import. For some reason importing the Types module directly didn't work -- well for Map at least.

```js
import { Document, Schema, model, Query, Model } from "mongoose";

{
   ...
   metadata: { type: Schema.Types.Map, of: String, required: false },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"name" is not a valid attribute anymore in mongoose schemas. Replace it with "type" it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man this is related to wrong name of the schema fields in my case:

```
    participants: [
        {
            typeof: Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    ]
```

and I got same error as you. I was so struggled and this typeof - type f* VS code I'm using it at the moment cause this computer can't deal with jet brains, :(